# TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined - TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, foreach

```
if (dataFindCategories && dataFindCategories.length !== 0) {
    let dataFindProducts: Product[];
    dataFindCategories.forEach((category) => {          
        dataFindProducts.concat(this.productRepository.findByCategory(category.id));
    });
}
```

Quando este forEach é executado ele me retorna este erro:

> - TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Para cada `category` ele ira fazer uma busca pelo `ID` que me retornara um `Product[]`, eu preciso concatenar cada retorno em uma variável, no caso a `dataFindProducts`

Comment: isso retornar o que: `productRepository.findByCategory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está declarando a variável, mas não está inicializando ela, logo o seu `dataFindProducts` é igual a `undefined`, experimente inicializar ele com um array vazio

```
let dataFindProducts: Product[] = [];
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Ja que está utilizando o `superset` [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) utilize o tipo [Array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) (*que é o tipo generico*) da seguinte forma, ***exemplo minimo***:

```
class Produto {
    constructor(public id: number){    
    }
} 

class Category {
    constructor(public id: number){    
    }
}

const dataFindCategories = Array<Category>();
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(1));
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(2));
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(3));

let dataFindProducts = Array<Produto>();
dataFindCategories.forEach((category: Category) => {
    dataFindProducts = 
        dataFindProducts.concat(category.id);
});

console.log(dataFindProducts);
```

e preste atenção que ao utilizar `.concat` a última alteração deve ser retornada para a variável, porque `.concat` retorna outro `array`.

Um outra forma é com [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
class Produto {
    constructor(public id: number){
    }
} 

class Category {
    constructor(public id: number){
    }
}

const dataFindCategories = [];
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(1));
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(2));
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(3));
dataFindCategories.push(new Category(4));

let dataFindProducts = [];
dataFindCategories.forEach((category: Category) => {
    dataFindProducts = [... dataFindProducts, category.id]; // Spread
});
console.log(dataFindProducts);
```

Comment: Entendi!, obrigado!